# Como colocar em hierarquia

Tags: php, menu, dinâmico

Preciso criar um menu dinâmico aonde ele crie a hierarquia de acordo com o IdMenuPai porém infelizmente só estou conseguindo listar sem hierarquia, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
function montaMenuFilho($menu) {
    echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">';
    foreach ($menu as $item) {
        if(!empty($item->x      )) {
            echo '<li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#">
                        <i class="icon-puzzle"></i>'.$item->Descricao.'</a>';
            echo montaMenuFilho($item->Home);
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            if ($item->IdMenu == '27') {

                echo '<li class=""><a href="'.$item->Url.'" title="Necessário logar na ferramenta Power BI.">'.$item->Descricao.'</a></li>';

            } elseif ($item->IdMenu == '47') {

                echo '<li class=""><a href="'.$item->Url.'" title="Apenas para acompanhamento da entrada de recursos.">'.$item->Descricao.'</a></li>';

            } elseif ($item->IdMenu == '45') {

                echo '<li class=""><a href="'.$item->Url.'" title="Painel em validação">'.$item->Descricao.'</a></li>';

            } elseif ($item->IdMenu == '11' || $item->IdMenu == '23' || $item->IdMenu == '16' || $item->IdMenu == '17' || $item->IdMenu == '19' || $item->IdMenu == '12' || $item->IdMenu == '26') {

                echo '<li class=""><a target="_blank" href="'.$item->Url.'">'.$item->Descricao.'</a></li>';

            } else {

                echo '<li class=""><a href="'.$item->Url.'">'.$item->Descricao.'</a></li>';

            }
        }        
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="">
        <a href="http://10.31.40.74/novahome/">Home</a>
    </li>                 
    <?php                        
        foreach ($menu as $item) {
            if(!empty($item->Home)) {                                
                echo '<li class="menu-dropdown classic-menu-dropdown">
                            <a data-hover="megamenu-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                '.$item->Descricao.'<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                            </a>';
                echo montaMenuFilho($item);
                echo '</li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li class=""><a href="'.$item->Url.'">'.$item->Descricao.'</a></li>';
            }
        }  
    ?>             
</ul>
```

Comment: você precisa que a listagem seja de acordo com um numero x de visitas em cada item do menu? especifique melhor seu problema.

Comment: Arthur eu preciso listar os itens do idmenupai abaixo do idmenu... exemplo Item 1 tem o idmenu 1 todos os itens que tem o idmenupai 1 precisam entrar abaixo dele, no momento eu consigo somente listar todos os itens sem ordem específica.